# Unable to generate valid FCM token (unless they re-install iOS app)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Some of our users who have been using our app for 3+ months mentioned that they cannot receive FCM notifications. Upon further investigation, their FCM tokens are “not registered” with the following error:
`code: ‘messaging/registration-token-not-registered’, message: ‘The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.’`
We added a troubleshoot button in our app to regenerate their FCM token with two methods:
`Messaging.messaging().fcmToken`
`Messaging.messaging().token`

Both methods return the exact same token that FCM claims to be stale and “not registered”. Anyone know why this is the case? We're currently on Firebase SDK v8.8.0 and have looked at the FCM changelog from v8.11.0 - v10.12.0 but none of the updates seem to address this issue. This registration-token-not-registered error seems to be on Firebase's side and has nothing to do with APNS.

Can "unregistered" FCM tokens be cached by Firebase's iOS SDK internally such that the only way to clear that cache is to do a delete / reinstall the app? Re-installing seems to be the only way to fix this issue so far.